# one behavior about javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript

On Firefox

```
"aaa".match(/a?/g)
```

produces

```
["a", "a", "a", ""]
```

just curious why we have a empty string at the end of the array ?

as if the RE engine is to examine every character, the string only has 3 character, why produce 4 matches ?

Comment: ok, so the engine will take 4 tries, a a a and "" .

Answer (score 2):

The empty string is a valid match. The only reason it didn't match it before, is that `?` is greedy. So the match `"a"` is preffered, but when the engine hits the end of the string the only thing it can match is the empty string.

The engine doesn't count how many matches it has to do. After a match it simply countinues from the next character. After the third `a`, what's left is the empty string:

```
>>> "".match(/a?/g)
[""]
```